# MirrorMaker Cross DC Deployment Setup

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a question regarding MirrorMaker. I see that in the official documentation (see https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=27846330), MirrorMaker is placed on the destination data center. Is there a good reason why it can't be placed on the Source data center instead?

I'm asking because in our current setup, MirrorMaker is placed on the destination data center and what we are seeing is that simply owning the partitions on startup or a rebalance takes a long time.

Our Setup is like so:

- 6 Total Kafka Clusters Across 4 Data Centers
- Each Data Centers has a Local Kafka Cluster
- 2 Aggregate Kafka Clusters in 2 of the Data Centers
- 400+ topics in each Local Kafka Cluster
- 2 Groups of MirrorMakers on the same Data Center as their respective destination Aggregate Kafka Clusters that consumes from all 4 Local Kafka Clusters
- MirrorMaker Instances are Configured to pull 400+ topics with with a catch all regex from the 4 Local Kafka Clusters to the Aggregate Clusters
- Our Kafka Versions are 0.8.2.1 with offsets stored in Zookeeper

Our issue currently is that on MirrorMaker restart / consumer-rebalance partition ownership takes over 30+ mins when consuming from Local Kafkas in different data centers.

My guess is that the partition ownership process has to go across data centers to the source Kafka Zookeepers, and this cross DC connections are slowing down the MirrorMaker partition ownership process.

I was thinking of moving MirrorMaker to the Source data center instead, to speed up partition ownership on a startup / rebalance. But I was wondering if anyone has tried this setup and if there were any issues with this approach?

Comment: We tested out this setup since a couple of weeks ago and it works well. We are able to rebalance consumers and startup MirrorMaker in less than a minute. If anyone else is wondering, this setup works and we are pretty happy with the outcome. We went from 30+ mins for a consumer rebalance on MirrorMaker to less than a min.

Answer (score 2):

The mirror maker is used high level consumer to consume from the source cluster. By default the mirror maker itself takes much time while re-balancing. Its not your own problem. See where the uber struck with mirror maker and how they overcome it with uReplicator (https://eng.uber.com/ureplicator/). Hope helps